# Angular DOM sanitizer: How to keep accents in message input?

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer, accent-sensitive

I am using DomSanitizer to search if there are any scripts inside an message(a formgroup of the site). The scripting part works, but if I use any accent inside the message, it get's changed . How to solve this?

`this.formGroup.value.message= this.sanitizer.sanitize( SecurityContext.HTML, this.formGroup.value.message );`

Sent message: "é"

content in BD:

message content

[image]

What's the best way to convert it for the user? And in your opinion, convert it back to normal in the backend or front?

Comment: If you aren’t allowing user-provided HTML (where `&#233;` should be equivalent to `é`), you don’t need to (and shouldn’t) search for scripts inside a message. (n.b. DomSanitizer would also be the wrong way to search for scripts for non-sanitizing reasons.)